# How to display a certain number of items from an array list in one row

Tags: javascript

I am displaying all my items from the list using `drivers2020.forEach(addLink);`.
 All of them are displaying in one row, is there a way to set a number of items, that will be displayed in one row and when that number is reached, start a new one?

Here's  how my function looks like:

```
drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  wrapper.style.width = "250px";
  wrapper.style.float = "left";
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.id = `listOfNames`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  const driverImg = document.createElement('img');
  driverImg.src = driver.image;
  wrapper.appendChild(driverImg);
  wrapper.appendChild(nameList);
  list2020.appendChild(wrapper);
  nameList.addEventListener('click', function () {
    driverProfile(driver, this)
  });
}
```

Comment: Use CSS for that purpose: that’s what it’s for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with your existing code is to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```
#list2020 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

You can adjust the number of columns by manipulating this line here:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`

```js
const drivers2020 = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
  }
];
const list2020 = document.getElementById('list2020');
drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  wrapper.style.width = "250px"; 
  wrapper.style.float = "left"; 
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.id = `listOfNames`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  const driverImg = document.createElement('img');
  driverImg.src = driver.image;
  wrapper.appendChild(driverImg);
  wrapper.appendChild(nameList);
  list2020.appendChild(wrapper);
  nameList.addEventListener('click', function() {
  driverProfile(driver, this)
});
}
```

```css
#list2020 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list2020"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways, one of them is below code, copy and paste it in [*here*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_elementcreate) to see the result (You can change width and margin to have different number of columns)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
</div>

<script>
const arrayOfItems = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]

arrayOfItems.forEach((item) => {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(item);

    para.appendChild(node);

    para.style.width = "31.33%"
    para.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    para.style.display = "inline-block"
    para.style.marginLeft = "1%"
    para.style.marginRight = "1%"

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    container.appendChild(para);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```